# what do these neo4j 2.0.1 exceptions mean?

Tags: java, neo4j

We embed Neo4j 2.0.1 community edition on Linux 64 and JRE 1 7 51 in a multi-threaded application.

*Intermittently* (rarely) we get following exceptions when we delete a Relationship and execute a cypher within same transaction, respectively.

Should we be using pessimistic locks for these deletes? what do these exceptions mean?

**ResourceAcquisitionFailedException**

```
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.ResourceAcquisitionFailedException: The transaction is marked for rollback only.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager$ResourceHolder.enlist(PersistenceManager.java:408)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager$ResourceHolder.forWriting(PersistenceManager.java:384)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.KernelTransactionImplementation.ensureWriteTransaction(KernelTransactionImplementation.java:181)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.KernelTransactionImplementation.upgradeToDataTransaction(KernelTransactionImplementation.java:211)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.KernelStatement.dataWriteOperations(KernelStatement.java:84)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.RelationshipProxy.delete(RelationshipProxy.java:84)
```

**org.neo4j.cypher.CypherExecutionException**

```
org.neo4j.cypher.CypherExecutionException at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compiler$v2_0$spi$ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$$translateException(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:151)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.getLabelsForNode(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:44)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.DelegatingQueryContext.getLabelsForNode(DelegatingQueryContext.scala:39)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.QueryContext$class.isLabelSetOnNode(QueryContext.scala:54)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.DelegatingQueryContext.isLabelSetOnNode(DelegatingQueryContext.scala:26)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.commands.HasLabel.isMatch(Predicate.scala:252)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.commands.And.isMatch(Predicate.scala:62)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.commands.And.isMatch(Predicate.scala:62)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.commands.Predicate.isTrue(Predicate.scala:33)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.pipes.matching.SingleStep$FilteringIterator.isValidNext(SingleStep.scala:135)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.pipes.matching.SingleStep$FilteringIterator.computeNext(SingleStep.scala:118)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.pipes.matching.SingleStep$FilteringIterator.next(SingleStep.scala:108)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.pipes.matching.SingleStep$FilteringIterator.next(SingleStep.scala:98)
        at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$IteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala:30)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.TraversalBranchImpl.next(TraversalBranchImpl.java:138)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.TraversalBranchWithState.next(TraversalBranchWithState.java:32)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.StartNodeTraversalBranch.next(StartNodeTraversalBranch.java:50)
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.traversal.PreorderDepthFirstSelector.next(PreorderDepthFirstSelector.java:49)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.MonoDirectionalTraverserIterator.fetchNextOrNull(MonoDirectionalTraverserIterator.java:68)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.MonoDirectionalTraverserIterator.fetchNextOrNull(MonoDirectionalTraverserIterator.java:35)
        at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.hasNext(PrefetchingIterator.java:55)
        at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.hasNext(Wrappers.scala:41)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$14.hasNext(Iterator.scala:388)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.isEmpty(Iterator.scala:256)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.isEmpty(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.pipes.SlicePipe.internalCreateResults(SlicePipe.scala:36)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:71)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:68)
         at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:71)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:68)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compiler$v2_0$executionplan$ExecutionPlanBuilder$$prepareStateAndResult(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:149)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder$$anonfun$2.apply(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:126)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder$$anonfun$2.apply(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:125)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder$$anon$6.execute(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:50)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ExecutionPlanWrapperForV2_0.execute(CypherCompiler.scala:93)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:61)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:65)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.java:78)
```

Comment: Can you provide the operations and the Cypher query you execute ? From what I understand from the exception, you try to perform additional operations on a transaction that is already rolled-back.